# Simple example from book "OpenGL Superbible" compiles and links, but doesn't run

Tags: visual-c++, opengl

I'm new to OpenGL programming. I'm starting with a simple example from "OpenGL Superbible". The program compiled and linked, but after starting the program the function `glewInit()` has an error. The return from function is `1` and the following error message is:

> "Missing GL version".

I don't understand this. Visual Studio loaded the OpenGL.dll, but didn't load the atioglxx.dll.

The OpenGL extension viewer says: The computer installed the OpenGL version 3.2 and some extensions from 3.3 and 4.0.

I am using Visual C++ 2008 Express and the static lib from freeglut (2.6) and the GLTools from the book.

Thanks for your help.

Dirk

Here is the code from the example:  [code from example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629351/glu-h-problems)

Comment: This would suggest to me that you don't have a valid OpenGL context yet.

Comment: Thank you, for the answer. What you mean with a valid OpenGL context. I think the function glewInit create a valid OpenGL context.

Comment: glewInit does not create an opengl context. ( http://glew.sourceforge.net/basic.html ) This has to be done before. You use exactly the same code as at the link you posted? There a valid context should have been created. You don't get any errors on the calls before? Do all those calls succeed?

Comment: This solution was very stupid. I forget the following line glutCreateWindow("Triangle"); This create the valid OpenGL context. Now is program running without errors. Thank you for your answer.